# Non-block setTimeout for web server

Tags: javascript, http, express, web, timeout

I have a web server that upon request makes a phone call, waits 3 seconds and then checks if that phone call is still ongoing. I used `setTimeout` to integrate this but this blocks all other connections to the web server until the timeout has finished.

```
// example get request
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  // take an action
  example.makeCall(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      // check the action
      example.checkCall(function() {
        res.status(200)
      })
    }, 3000)
  })
})
```

Is there some other way of adding a timeout to a request without blocking all other incoming requests?

Comment: Nope. setTimeout is NOT blocking.

Comment: It shouldn't be blocking the web server.  What makes you think that?

Comment: It's in how you are implementing it that makes it 'seem' to block.  Use setInterval instead and if you get the status you're looking for, move on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your additional API requests are being blocked, new API requests should use a new invocation of your route's callback function on the call stack and shouldn't be dependant on previous callback functions finishing to be added to the call stack.

The issue might not be that the setTimeout is blocking and may be another problem such as your phone call API blocking new calls being made before a previous call has finished.

But something to try could be to wait 3 seconds in a promise to try to get around potential blocking.

```
function waitThree() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve();
    }, 3000);
  });
}

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  // take an action
  example.makeCall(function() {
    waitThree.then(function() {
      example.checkCall(function() {
        res.status(200)
      });
    });
  })
});
```